# Why one query returns more than other

Tags: sql, oracle, null, subquery, nvl

Using the following question could you please explain to me what's the difference between the two SQLs and why they do not have the same result?

**Display the last name, department name, and salary of any employee whose salary and commission match the salary and commission of any employee located in location ID1700.**

```
SELECT E.LAST_NAME, D.DEPARTMENT_NAME, E.SALARY
  FROM EMPLOYEES E
  JOIN DEPARTMENTS D
    ON (E.DEPARTMENT_ID =D.DEPARTMENT_ID)
  WHERE E.SALARY IN (SELECT SALARY
                       FROM EMPLOYEES
                       WHERE D.LOCATION_ID = 1700) AND
        E.COMMISSION_PCT IN (SELECT COMMISSION_PCT
                               FROM EMPLOYEES
                               WHERE D.LOCATION_ID = 1700);
```

(0 outputs)

and

```
SELECT e.last_name, d.department_name, e.salary
  FROM employees e,
       departments d
  WHERE e.department_id = d.department_id AND
        (salary, NVL(commission_pct,0)) IN (SELECT salary, 
                                                   NVL(commission_pct,0)
                                              FROM employees e,
                                                   departments d
                                              WHERE e.department_id = d.department_id AND
                                                    d.location_id = 1700);
```

(36 outputs)

Comment: Which database are you actually using?  I'm guessing Oracle, and I'm also guessing this is a homework problem.

Comment: Yes, Oracle DB.
Im trying to figure out why the 0 outputs one doesn't work. (i wrote that myself).
The solution for the question is the one with the 36 outputs.
I don't know why the SQL i type isn't correct, looks correct to me but is apparently not based on results.

Comment: Add some sample table data, and the current two results. (As well formatted text.) Also show us the wanted result.

Comment: This looks like sample tables and queries from the Oracle SQL samples, can you post your sample data as well so we can re-create?

Comment: @MigsIsip - this is the standard HR schema that comes with every Oracle installation (almost). If you have access to Oracle, you should have access to the schema. (And if you don't, it's hard to see how you could "recreate" anyway!)

Comment: @mathguy, i've always used Oracle EBS Environment so i don't have those schema in the Database. :(

Comment: @MigsIsip - hard to believe. Rather, they may never have been activated by your DBA? According to the documentation (for example https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E26401_01/doc.122/e22952/T156458T659606.htm) the standard schemas, and `HR` in particular, are included in EBS.

Answer (score 2):

Note that this query:

```
SELECT e.last_name, d.department_name, e.salary
  FROM employees e,
       departments d
  WHERE e.department_id = d.department_id AND
        (salary, NVL(commission_pct,0)) IN (SELECT salary, 
                                                   NVL(commission_pct,0)
                                              FROM employees e,
                                                   departments d
                                              WHERE e.department_id = d.department_id AND
                                                    d.location_id = 1700);
```

... will include any employee that has the same salary and commission as someone in location 1700. By consequence all employees in location 1700 will be included in the result set. But other employees, not in that location, could be found as well, if only there is someone in location 1700 that has exactly the same salary and commission. So this query answers correctly to the given assignment.

However, the other query has an odd condition in both sub queries, in that it applies a condition on the outer query (the only place where `D` is defined) -- not the sub query -- and it does so twice (which does not help):

```
SELECT E.LAST_NAME, D.DEPARTMENT_NAME, E.SALARY
  FROM EMPLOYEES E
  JOIN DEPARTMENTS D
    ON (E.DEPARTMENT_ID =D.DEPARTMENT_ID)
  WHERE E.SALARY IN (SELECT SALARY
                       FROM EMPLOYEES
                       WHERE D.LOCATION_ID = 1700) AND
        E.COMMISSION_PCT IN (SELECT COMMISSION_PCT
                               FROM EMPLOYEES
                               WHERE D.LOCATION_ID = 1700);
```

You would not change anything substantial if you would move that condition on `location_id` in the outer `where` clause. And now it becomes clear that this query ***excludes*** any employees that are not in location 1700 -- this is not always true for the other query.

Furthermore, this one does not have the `NVL` function applied to `commission_pct`, which means that employees will be excluded also if they have `null` as `commission_pct`. This is because `NULL IN (SELECT ...)` ***always*** evaluates to false.

So there are two reasons why this query can return fewer records, and also why it is the wrong answer to the assignment you got.

Comment: thanks sir, is there any simpler way to rewrite the query using my method? Possible to use a JOIN?
And i do not really understand what does "You would not change anything substantial if you would move that condition on location_id in the outer where clause." mean...

Comment: Sorry, I thought your question was *"what's the difference between the two SQLs and why they do not have the same result?"*. Now you ask to rewrite the query? If that is your question, please post a new question (no problem). My comment on the condition on `location_id` means that this condition does not refer to anything in the subquery, and so is quite misleading. It is a condition on the outer query, so it should be put there. And I am saying that such a move would not change the result. But it clarifies better what happens.